# Do not compress video when I select a video

Tags: ios, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am making Video Upload App in IOS.
I got a problem on UIImagePickerController.

That is,
When I whenever select a Movie, It compressed automatically.

I had tried every VideoQuality Options. (High, Medium, Low)

Do I use other Controller or my own Controller?

A short video(5 minutes) compression spends very long time(several minutes) on my iPhone(4S).

I think that my app supports over 10 minute video at least.

My Code are like this.

```
- (void)showImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType
{   
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:sourceType]) {
        [picker setSourceType:sourceType];
        [picker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]];
        // Video Quality Setting..
        [picker setVideoQuality:UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)showLibrary:(id)sender
{
    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum];
}

- (IBAction)showCamera:(id)sender
{
    [self showImagePicker:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
}
```

Comment: Can you show in code how you are extracting a movie and making it available for uploading? And what's wrong with any compression? Is it just adding too much time to the process? Wouldn't you want compression if you are sending up through a cellular network?